# How to do Wordpress Custom Post multiple rewrite?

Tags: wordpress

how to rewrite below custom post in Wordpress
Live

http://example.org/custompost/post-title

Need as

http://example.org/category/subcategory/custompost-title

Answer (score 1):

You need to update permalink from `wp-admin/options-permalink.php` here

Select "Custom Structure"  and add this pattern after site URL `/%category%/%postname%/`.

Now create category and subcategory for post types and assign child category to specific post like (if I have a test(parent) and test2(child) and create test post type then I will select child category (test2) only).

Now you can able to see your pattern in post URL like http://example.org/category/subcategory/custompost-title

Comment: It won't work, There are 5 custom post and each custom post have 3 Category

Comment: I didn't get you. Please explain more. Those 3 are main category or sub-category?